# Xamarin.Forms Different View Per Platform and Device

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a project in **Xamarin.Forms**, and i'm trying to create 4 views: **Android** phone, **Android** tablet, **iPhone** and **iPad**. I've tried a little example, something like this in the **XAML**:

```
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <ContentView>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
                    <On Platform="iOS">
                        <!-- Use view for iOS here -->
                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="View">
                            <OnIdiom.Phone>
                                <Frame x:Name="MainFrameiPhone">
                                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#FF00FF">       
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>
                            </OnIdiom.Phone>
                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                <Frame x:Name="MainFrameiPad">
                                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#00FF00">       
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>
                            </OnIdiom.Tablet>                        
                        </OnIdiom>                     
                    </On>
                    <!--Same for android -->
                    <On Platform="Android">
                        ...
                    </On>
                </OnPlatform>
            </ContentView>           
        </ContentPage.Content>
```

But i don't want to rename each frame and component i use in the 4 views (For example `MainFrameiPhone` and `MainFrameiPad`).

I'm doing it right? or can i create 4 views and call each one from the code behind?

What's the better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ControlTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/creating) .

```
public class MainFrameiPhone: Frame
{
  public TealTemplate ()
  {
    ...
    // set the content here 
  }
}

public class MainFrameiPad: Frame
{
  ...
}
```

#### in content page

```
ControlTemplate mainFrameiPhone= new ControlTemplate(typeof(MainFrameiPhone));
ControlTemplate mainFrameiPad= new ControlTemplate(typeof(MainFrameiPad));
//...
```

```
public MainPage()
{
   //...
        ContentView content = new ContentView() {

            Content = {

                //...
            }



        };

        if(Device.RuntimePlatform=="iOS")
        {
            if(Device.Idiom==TargetIdiom.Phone)
            {
                content.ControlTemplate = mainFrameiPhone;
            }
            else if(Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
            {
                content.ControlTemplate = mainFrameiPad;
            }
        }

        else if(Device.RuntimePlatform == "Android")
        {
            if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
            {
                content.ControlTemplate = xxx;
            }
            else if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
            {
                content.ControlTemplate = xxx;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            content.ControlTemplate = xxx;
        }

        Content = content;
}
```